# See Difference between 2 branches on BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to compare my dev and master branches on Bitbucket. Unfortunately, Bitbucket seems to use commits to do diffs rather than the actual state of the branches. Therefore, in cases where I have made a commit to dev, and then created a different branch for master that I then merge directly into master, Bitbucket sees a difference even though there actually is no difference. This is frustrating.

Is it possible to see the actual difference between 2 branches? If not in Bitbucket, than in Jetbrains or VSCode, and if not there, then at least in git itself?

I feel like I have to get both branches to have common commits. Is a merge or a rebase appropriate here?

Comment: A branch _is_ a commit. It's simply a name for the latest commit. Why not skip the middleman and just use Git? [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) You might look into `cherry-pick` or rebase rather than making identical changes on different branches.

Comment: Can you replace the commit IDs with branch names? The behavior might differ between Bitbucket Cloud and Bitbucket Server, and it might have changed since I last looked, but BB Cloud would let you specify branch names in place of commit IDs in any URL (it'd show the HEAD for the specified branch).

Comment: Your explanation doesn't really make sense. If the commits are different, Bitbucket will show the difference. If they both reference the same tree, then there is no difference. You can't have both at the same time. I don't know what you mean with "created a different branch for master that I then merge directly into master". A branch is a label for a commit and nothing more. Using the branch name is equivalent to the latest commit of that branch when using `git diff`.

Comment: In other words: the "state of a branch" is its latest _commit_. The trees of the commits are compared/diffed. There is no additional information stored in branches. Whenever you specify a branch name with `git diff`, the names are resolved to commits before calculating the actual diff.

Comment: @knittl, I mean that I would branch from dev, make a change, and then merge into dev. Ideally I would merge dev into master, but often there are other changes in dev that we don't want in master. So I would create a new branch from master, make the same change, and then merge into master. So I would have the same content but under 2 different commits in dev and master. Obviously, this is not the right way of doing things. Can you confirm that the right way is to create a new branch from master and then cherry-pick from dev into the new branch and then merge into master?

Comment: @PythonDeveloper "cherry-picking" and "doing the same changes on another branch, then committing" is the same thing. There's no difference: you will end up with two independent commits for both. There is no single "right" way, but usually, you'd merge your changes. I'm still not sure which "difference between branches" you are asking for. Are you looking for [`git cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) or [`git range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumptions and Suggestions

I think you have a process problem as opposed to a tool problem.

Your question is not very clear. My assumption is that you are operating with 2 lifetime branches, `dev` and `master` where `dev` is ahead of `master` for a strategic period of time (say a sprint). This is at base similar to the GitFlow branching strategy.
[image]

With this, I hear then that you've made a change to `dev` and pushed, then branched from `master` (call it `feat/123`) and made the same changes before merging back to `master`.

If this is the case, then your changes, though identical in content, are tracked as different commit hashes and therefore git is going to show them as a difference.

If you would want to have the end result be that `dev` and `master` show no diff, I would suggest you cut the branch from `master` first (again calling it `feat/123`), and make changes there. Then you are free to merge `feat/123` into `master` (say for a hotfix) and also into `dev` in whatever order you see fit (our org would merge to `dev` first and test the changes there before merging to `main`).

Cutting your feature branch from master, is very similar operating a trunk based branch strategy where you assume `master` is always "clean" and `dev` may be dirty.
[image]

With this you make the change once and merge twice so that the exact commit is put into the target branches. This will prevent the undesired diff between your `master` and `dev` branches.

This won't work if your feature branch must be build on previous work merged into `dev`.

#### Information is King

You asked in your question about `cherry-pick` and `rebase`. I would recommend you understand clearly what commands like `cherry-pick` or `rebase` do before using them. Git docs and StackOverflow are great for that. Using `cherry-pick` or `rebase` between the `feat/123` branch and the targets will result in your current situation as those operations write new commits to the tree.

### Mending your current situation

If you need to have your current situation done such that the diff with equal content is removed I would suggest simply reverting the commit to `dev` and then merge the `feat/123` branch you cut from `master` into `dev`.

If you must do this without a `revert + merge`, then you can (given you have permissions to force push) get the result you're looking for by rebasing `dev` with `master` interactively (`rebase -i`). This may not be a great option depending on the amount of other differences between your 2 lifetime branches, but in the interactive flow you can use `-d` option to drop the commit that holds the identical changes from `dev` and keep all other desired changes. Again, keep in mind that `rebase` will "replay" your dev changes on the new tip (or specified commit) of `master`, meaning the hashes of your commits in `dev` will change (which is why force push permissions are required). ***BE SURE*** to collaborate with your team before you do this on a shared branch or it will disrupt their local versions and create a lot of mess.

#### If the stars align

If the stars align such that your commit to dev is not "on top of" other untested code, then you could just as easily cut a branch from `dev` at the commit you want to move forward, and merge that branch into `master` (you'd need to revert your manual cherry-pick changes). Then when you merge `dev` into `master` it will see that commit is already there and you won't have a diff caused by a separate commit.

This is a **tactical** operation that is only valid in a certain subset of scenarios, it is not a **strategic** solution to all situations of this kind.

If you are wanting a strategic solution, I would recommend transitioning your team and process to orient around a trunk based development with more testing and validation prior to merging.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, @Josh Gust! Your assumption was indeed correct: I would have 2 different branches with the same content that I merged into dev and master respectively. The reason for this is because oftentimes I would have code in dev ready to be promoted to master, but my coworker would have code in dev that was not ready to go to master. So I created a branch from master and made the same changes there and then merged into master. Now, to answer the question that you're thinking of whether I used the same commits from dev, the answer is sometimes yes and sometimes no.

Comment: What is the proper way to handle this common situation? If the code I want in master is already in dev, is the best approach to create a new branch from master and then cherry-pick exactly those commits from dev that I want in master so that I don't introduce any code from dev that is not ready to be promoted?

Comment: Asking for "proper" is asking for subjective input. My subjective response would be stop using multiple lifetime branches. Though this may not be under your control I would encourage your team to begin operating on a trunk based model with short-lived feature branches that are functionally tested prior to merging, and integration + regression tested after. This direction puts you closer to having real release candidates in your trunk.

Comment: My 2 cents on correcting your current situation are in my answer. Other people with deeper proficiency in git may offer a different or better solution, but given this is a shared branch, interactive rebase with `-d` option is likely going to cause more headache. I would, if I were in a bind for time an needed this diff to go away, revert my `dev` change and merge my feature branch from `master`. For future cases, cherry-pick will get your changes from `dev` into `master` w/o bringing everything else along too, but it will **still** appear in `master` under a different commit.

Answer (score 1):

I'll cite bitbucket documentation : https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/compare-branches-tags-and-commits-970595881.html

```
Bitbucket uses git diff ...

A three-dot diff is a comparison between the commit where the feature branch was last synched with the destination branch and the most recent version of the feature branch.

A two-dot diff is the direct comparison of two committish references such as SHAs.
```

What's important to note here is the "LAST SYNCHED". bitbucket will therefore FAIL to show you the diff you seek to see. What's worse, is bitbucket diff tool is showing you the 2 commits you chose, even it is not using effectively those commits.

If you want to see a real diff, I advice you to use IntelliJ integrated features that are truly awsome. You can use free IntelliJ Community edition which offers the best git integration and tools you'll ever find.

(and forget about bitbucket diff tool)